# How to bind Tomcat to a domain and port in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, api, tomcat, domain-name

I have a Spring Boot API process running on a server. I can reach it with https://{IP}/api/test. But when I try to use the domain name, it doesn't resolve. For example, https://{domain}/api/test

I also have ActiveMQ Artemis running on this server, reachable at https://{domain}:8443  This resolves fine.

So what am I missing here? Do I need to add a configuration to Spring to Tomcat will bind to the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot application doesn't take any decision about being accessible by IP or domain name, so it's probably not related to spring boot.

Since you say, that the messaging system is accessible through DNS, I assume you don't have DNS-related issues.

So one possible direction to check is whether the spring boot application is running behind some kind of proxy (nginx, apache, haproxy), whatever. These can be configured in a way that they won't let you connect by DNS.

See [this link for example](https://serverfault.com/questions/932090/spring-endpoints-work-with-ip-but-not-domain-name-how-to-fix)